# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am making a post request from angularJs to web api. but every time I'm getting this error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:45525/api/account/register. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:45725' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

I'm following this [**tutorial**](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)

to solve this problem, I have also installed

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

Then I added

```
config.EnableCors();
```

inside `WebApiConfig` Register Method.

and also I added

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
    public class AccountController : ApiController
    {
        private AuthRepository _repo = null;

        public AccountController()
        {
            _repo = new AuthRepository();
        }

        // POST api/Account/Register
        [EnableCors("*", "*", "PUT, POST")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("Register")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(UserModel userModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            IdentityResult result = await _repo.RegisterUser(userModel);

            return Ok();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _repo.Dispose();
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
}
```

at account controller. But still I'm getting same problem.

AngularCode

```
var _saveRegistration = function (registration) {
  var serviceBase = 'http://localhost:45525/';
  _logOut();

  return $http.post(serviceBase + 'api/account/register', registration)
     .then(function (response) {
            return response;
     }); 
};
```

Comment: Are you sure that a POST is being performed and not a GET?

Comment: From what you say you've done, then CORS should be enabled.  Can you show code `AcccountController`.

Comment: Try `[EnableCors("*", "*", "PUT,POST")]`, that is remove space between methods.

Comment: @RichardSchneider: Thank you very much. It work. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the space between web methods in the CORS attribute

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "PUT,POST")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I have solved the problem in a different way.

If you followed the tutorial steps then:

1. you don't need `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` package
2. Add the following to the configuration section in `Web.config` as [here](https://github.com/tjoudeh/JWTAspNetWebApi/blob/master/AuthorizationServer.Api/Web.config)

   ```
   <system.webServer>
     <handlers>
       <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
       <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
       <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
       <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
     </handlers>
   </system.webServer>
   ```